# SCSS/SASS get values from nth nested maps

Tags: sass, nested, nested-lists, sass-maps

I'm having trouble trying to retrieve values within nested sass maps. I have a map that looks like this:

```
$breakpoints : (
    xl: (
         page-width: 1170px,
         gutter: 30px,
         base-font-size: 17px
    ),
    l: (
         breakpoint: 1170px,
         page-width: 980px,
         gutter: 20px,
         base-font-size: 17px
    )
);
```

I am trying to retrieve variables within the first nested list "xl". The idea is to retrieve the nested list by index and not by the key name as this should be able to by modified to the user's liking.

I would have thought that using `map-get(nth($breakpoints, 1), page-width)` would have worked but `nth($breakpoints, 1)` seems to return a string containing "xl (page-width: 1170px, gutter: 30px, base-font-size: 17px)" rather than an actual map and is therefor unusable with the `map-get()` function.

Any ideas on how to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can create a function that converts numeric indexes to string keys:

```
@function index-to-key($index) {
  $keys: map-keys($breakpoints); // A list of all keys in a $breakpoints map

  @return nth($keys, $index);
}
```

Then call this function:

```
width: map-get(map-get($breakpoints, index-to-key(1)), page-width);
```

Where inner `map-get` returns the map `xl` from `$breakpoints` and outer `map-get` returns value by key `page-width`.

---

Full code on [Sassmeister](https://www.sassmeister.com/gist/9747ab0ce961f45a48719e83c3db48eb).
`map-keys` function [description](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/Sass/Script/Functions.html#map_keys-instance_method).

Comment: Ahh that seems to do the job fine! thanks for the quick response :)